# iOS Simulators not appearing for Unity Build

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.1

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but since updating to XCode 7.1, I'm not seeing any option for deploying to simulators. I don't spend a ton of time in XCode so it may be just a setting somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. I had them before, and I've tried going into the Devices window and theres a list of them there, and the "Show in run destinations Menu" option is checked, but they don't appear when I try to deploy. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

[Devices are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQwyH.png)
[No Simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZAUA.png)
Thanks,

Dylan

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to choose "Simulator SDK" in the iOS player settings, or they're not available in Xcode. You cannot have both the simulator and the device builds in the same Xcode project from Unity.

Well... without mashing them together yourself.

Comment: Just realized that myself. Thanks for posting!

Comment: In case this isn't clear, in Unity -> Player settings -> iOS tab -> Other Settings -> Target SDK is where you set "Simulator SDK"

Comment: For those looking to set this property programmatically in Unity Scripting API, it's the property `PlayerSettings.iOS.sdkVersion` : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.iOS-sdkVersion.html

Answer (score 3):

This was a somewhat obvious answer once I figured it out, but hopefully this can help others. The issue wasn't with XCode but with the Unity build. I forgot to check the Build Settings > Target SDK> Build For Simulator flag in unity.